# 3D volume acrobatics in python.. selecting x/y/z rows/columns in 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm new to ndarrays in Numpy, so please be kind.
I have a 3D raw volume imported into numpy as a dtype uint8 array with shape
`(309L, 138L, 134L)` representing Z, Y, X dimensions.

The Raw image dimensions are (x,y,z), 134 138 309

This array is called `ThreeD`.

I can plot a Z 'section' of dimension XY of ThreeD with

```
ThreeD[70]
```

(selecting row 70)

I can plot a Y 'section' of dimension XZ of ThreeD with

```
ThreeD[:,70]
```

(selecting column 70)

but of course, there is the extra dimension! These first two are easy to reference, but I'm at a loss of how to select/reference the third dimension.. i.e.  the X section of dimension YZ (i.e. slicing a face of the matrix). I should add that I'm not entirely sure of the XZ/YZ dimension here, so those references might be reversed.

I got as far as I did using Sebastian Raschka's handy cheat sheet http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_matrix_cheatsheet.html

thanks kindly for any help

Comment: I think you want `ThreeD[70]` for `Z`, `ThreeD[:, 70]` for `Y`, and `ThreeD[:, :, 70]` (or `ThreeD[..., 70]`) for `X`.

Comment: What you show up there (`ThreeD[, 70]`) looks more like `R` to me ...

Comment: Jaime -- Excellent, thanks that works!! Can you post it as the answer?

Comment: Eickenberg -- sorry, you are right, that should've been ThreeD[:,70].. so I edited the question so I don't lead anyone astray who might venture in here in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`ThreeD[70]` for `Z`

`ThreeD[:, 70]` for `Y`

`ThreeD[:, :, 70]` or `ThreeD[..., 70]` for `X`

from Jaime. Thankyou.